# Removing the nan in python in an email

Tags: python, email, nan

I have created an auto email using python. Right now,I am trying to remove the nan details in my email as user don't want nan to be in the email. I'm not sure how to do it. Can anyone help me to add or edit the code below
This is my code :

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
from tabulate import tabulate
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import smtplib

user= 'mahirah.abd.wahab@ericsson.com'
password = '--------'
server = 'smtp.office365.com:587'
recipient = 'nur.suraya.shazwani.kamaru.zaman@ericsson.com,mahirah.abd.wahab@ericsson.com'

text = """
This is a test for the data to be sent

{table}

Regards,

Me"""

html = """
<html>
<head>
<style>
 This is a test auto generated email 
 table, th, td {{ border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; }}
  th, td {{ padding: 5px; }}
</style>
</head>
<body>
{table}
<p></p>
<p></p>
</body></html>
"""

# with open('input.csv') as input_file:
#     reader = csv.reader(input_file)
#     data = list(reader)

df = pd.read_csv('testcsv2.csv')
col_list = list(df.columns.values)
to_drop = []
for i in range(len(df)):
    if df['HOSS1 REVIEWED DATE'][i] == 'nan':
        to_drop.append(i)
df.drop(df.index[to_drop])
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
data = df


# above line took every col inside csv as list
text = text.format(table=tabulate(data, headers=col_list, tablefmt="grid"))
html = html.format(table=tabulate(data, headers=col_list, tablefmt="html"))

message = MIMEMultipart(
    "alternative", None, [MIMEText(text), MIMEText(html,'html')])

message['Subject'] = "Rental PR – Pending HOS Approval"
message['From'] = user
message['To'] = recipient
server = smtplib.SMTP(server)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login(user, password)
server.sendmail(user, recipient, message.as_string())
server.quit()
```

I also tried using this one line code , but still doesn't work :

df = pd.dropna(subset=['HOSS1 REVIEWED DATE'])

[THis is my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzjgB.png)

Appreciate if anyone can help.

Comment: what is the type of data in the col 'HOSS1 REVIEWED DATE'.. ?

Comment: the type of data in the column is date

Comment: sorry i meant the type of nan in the dataframe...is it str ?

Comment: it's okay , it is str

Comment: since the type is str dropna wont work...according to my knowledge there are multiple ways to drop the rows with nan, either loop and get the index of row with the nan value in the HOSS1 REVIEWED DATE column and then drop and reset, or you can convert the nan into NaN using the numpy module and then use dropna to drop the rows.

Comment: i see , can you show me a bit of the code as im not very familiar with it and im still quite new to python.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
to_drop = []
for i in range(len(df)):
    if df['HOSS1 REVIEWED DATE'][i] == 'nan':
        to_drop.append(i)
df.drop(df.index[to_drop], inplace=True)
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

Comment: @Hippiepina try now. I forgot the inplace param

Comment: Hi , it still doesn't work , can you check above, am i putting it at the right place?

Comment: is there any error ? if so what is it, also have you inserted the inplace=True param in df.drop ?